# sum the values in column for same date and id

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to add the values in the column `cost` ,`amt`- if there is a `flag`  1 and 2  for same  person `id` on same date.  please help. Thank you. Column are:

```
id  date    cost    amt flag
455 05/25/2013  150 110 1
455 05/25/2013  20  45  2
456 08/17/2013  140 60  1
456 08/17/2013  15  20  2
457 09/28/2013  135 10  1
457 09/28/2013  8   40  2
458 11/09/2013  10  30  1
```

output should be:

```
id  date    cost    amt flag
455 05/25/2013  170 155 1
456 08/17/2013  155 80  1
457 09/28/2013  143 50  1
458 11/09/2013  10  30  1
```

Comment: You want a `group by`

Comment: Have you tried anything?  If you can show us what you've tried, we'd be happy to help.

Comment: id 458 does not have a flag 2. should this be included in the results set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for diversity, check out my solution. It uses `over (partition by )` for calculation and `distinct` for filtering out the duplicates.

```
select distinct o.ID, o.Date,
  SUM(o.COST) OVER(PARTITION BY o.ID, o.Date) as cost
 ,SUM(o.AMT) OVER(PARTITION BY o.ID, o.Date) as amt
 ,MIN(FLAG) OVER(PARTITION BY o.ID, o.Date) as flag
from orders o
order by o.ID, o.Date
```

[SqlFiddle proof](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/181a3/26)

It's inspired by [this article](http://realworldsql.com/tag/sql-sum-partition-by/).

Comment: Wow.. it worked. Thank you. it added the values in the column. But the problem is I can still the duplicates of aggregated column. Is it because I have an auto increment first column. for eg:       Autoincre.  id  date    cost    amt flag
1     455 05/25/2013  170 110 1
2     455 05/25/2013  70  45  2
3     456 08/17/2013  155 60  1
4     456 08/17/2013  155 20  2
5     457 09/28/2013  143 10  1
6     457 09/28/2013  143  40  2
7     458 11/09/2013  10  30  1

Comment: Yeah, you would have to exclude unique record ID (autoincremental) from result set to make aggregation relevant

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what you want to do with flag, but you need `GROUP BY` like:

```
SELECT id, date, SUM(cost), Sum(amt), 1 as flag
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id,date
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT ID, DATE , SUM(COST),  SUM(AMT), MIN(Flag)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY ID, DATE`

Answer (score 0):

If you need flag 1 AND 2 in the same date for the same id then this should work:

```
SELECT id, date, SUM(cost), SUM(amt) , flag
FROM yourtable a
WHERE flag=1 
AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM yourtable b WHERE a.id=b.id AND b.flag=2 AND a.date=b.date)
GROUP BY id, date, flag
```